# Running Docker Container locally

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I've a docker image which is used in my Jenkins Pipeline to do a bunch of stuff such as building and running tests. Those tests uses docker. The image runs perfectly fine on the Jenkins Pipeline. I'm trying to connect to that images locally. I've followed the steps below:

```
1. docker-compose build
2. docker run -it container_name /bin/bash
```

After entering the container, I want to run the tests that use docker and getting the error below:
`connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock`

Also, I tried running `docker ps` I'm getting this:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Any suggestions for this?

Edit 1: my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  build:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    entrypoint: sh
    command: >
      sh -c "npm install"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM Imageeee

USER root

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm run build
```

Comment: Does the account you are using have suffient privileges to run this command?

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen Yes

Comment: What exactly are you building, from the looks of it, a docker in docker container(?), and trying to connect to `docker` inside of the `dind` container, would need to start the docker daemon inside of the container first (as you're overriding the `CMD`) and that's assuming the `dind` service is running as a `--priviliged` container [as per the doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker).

Comment: @masseyb yes, a docker in docker container

Comment: @curious_coder please update the question with a copy of your `docker-compose.yml` spec. I suspect that because you're overriding the `CMD` the `dockerd` process isn't starting, and can't connect if it's not started ofc.

Comment: @curious_coder that does not appear to be a docker in docker build, what is the actual `FROM Imageeee`?

Comment: @masseyb It is a custom image

Comment: @curious_coder does the custom image extend e.g. `docker:x.y.x-dind`?

Comment: @masseyb Yes it does

Comment: @curious_coder ok, I think I see your issue here, you have the config declared in your `docker-compose.yml` but you're doing a `docker run ...` (the `docker-compose` spec isn't used), you could do a `docker-compose run ...` (which would use the defined spec) or update your command e.g. `docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...`.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

`docker run` doesn't use the configuration defined in the `docker-compose.yml` spec. Not mounting the `docker` daemon socket, and without running the `docker` daemon inside the container, there is no `docker` daemon to connect to.

[image: no dockerd to connect to]

---

You can define your service configuration in YAML format:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  build:
    image: docker:20.10.12-dind
    container_name: dind
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

... then use `docker-compose run ...` to create a container

[image: docker-compose run example]

... or update the `docker run` command line, e.g.:

```shell
docker run --rm -it \
    --entrypoint docker \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    docker:20.10.12-dind ps
```

[image: docker run example]